# HttpUrlConnection isn work with mobile data

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I use httpUrlConnection to get information from the server. When I run it on Android, if the device is connected to Wi-Fi, there is no problem, but when I use mobile data, No information is received from the server.

My Codes:

```
new Thread(){

 @Override public void run(){

 try {
 URL u = new URL("https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/63a744c0dfc68e59d570253e");
 HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
 c.setRequestMethod("GET");
 c.connect();
 InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
 final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
 bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.


 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {

     TextView t = findViewById(R.id.tv);
     t.setText("bo.toString");
     

 try
 {
 bo.close();
 }catch(IOException e){ 
 e.printStackTrace();
 } }
 });

 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();

 } catch (ProtocolException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();

 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } }
 }.start();
```

I tried different Internet operators  and I reinstalled application But again the information was not received.

Comment: Where are you sending which information to the server. And what is bo?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I do not send information to the server. I receive information and display it on a TextView. And bo is a ByteArrayOutputStream.